# NodeJS + MySQL not returning rows

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm writing a database layer to an application that I'm working on. It's writen in NodeJS and uses the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) npm package to query the MySql database.

It's been working great, by now I've writen a lot of methods that are working fine. But this one is not returning the select rows. The select is valid, if I run it on database it returns the rows I want. But when using the method (as i've been using in all other methods) it doesn't work and I still don't understand why. Function code below:

```
DbContext.prototype.getItemsOwnedById = function db_getItemsOwnedById(steamId, itemIds, callback)
{
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE OwnedBy=' + connection.escape(steamId) + ' and Id in (';

    for (var i = 0; i < itemIds.length; i++) {
        query += connection.escape(itemIds[i]);

        if (i < itemIds.length - 1) {
           query += ', ';
        }
    }
    query += ')';

    console.log(query); // getting the query to check if it works. It does

    connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
            return;
        }

        console.log(rows); // empty array. Didn't return rows from DB

        if (rows.length == 0)
            callback(null, null);
        else
            callback(null, rows);
    });
}
```

Can you see something I'm missing? This code is very similar to the other ones that are working, basically what changes is the query. It doesn't throw errors.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you paste the query from the `console.log` in to the question ?

Comment: I'm unable to edit the question so here is the query: SELECT * FROM items where OwnedBy='76561198079655544' and Id in ('3144951047','3144951069','3144951095');

It puts 'number' but in workbench it returns. I tried generating the query without ' and it doesn't work too.

Comment: interesting the query looks good and there should not be an issue of long integer since the numbers are quoted and are represented as string so it should not create issue.Also its not falling to `err` meaning the query is getting executed. Not really sure whats going on, may be you can just hardcore one query into the function and see if this returns data.

Comment: Hum... hardcoding the query between "query" it works. I Just don't understand why, yet. Thanks for the tip! If I solve it I will post here the answer!

Comment: Just recommendation, have a look at knex.js it's really nice. I started using knex.js recently and love it. Example knex.select('*').from('items').where('OwnedBy', steamId) .andWhereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])

Comment: +Molda 57 thanks for the tip. I was reading and it makes me remeber entity framework a lot. By know, I will avoid anything that adds processing time to the process, but thanks anyway

Comment: Resolved. Embarassing, the problem was with JS + bigint rounding. The function is right, the problem was with rounding in another part before calling the function. Thanks for all the help!